# Which distribution to choose in boosting when dataset ist binary in gbm package

Tags: r, distributions, adaboost

I want to use the `gbm` package for boosting. As one can see, my data is completely binary and I'm kinda stuck which distribtion I should choose. 
I'm picking all the distributions from the documentation, which confuse me:

`Laplace` (absolute loss) - does that mean, that it's just like a classification error?

`bernoulli` (logistic regression for 0-1 outcomes), ok but

`huberized` (huberized hinge loss for 0-1 outcomes), classes),

`adaboost` (the AdaBoost exponential loss for 0-1 outcomes) also seem to be appropriate for 0-1 outcomes. So what is the right one in that particular dataset?

```
str(df)
data.frame':    1201 obs. of  321 variables:
$ Y   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ KC35: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
$ KP5Z: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
$ KG9J: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 ... 
...
```

Comment: Usually `bernoulli` would be the obvious choice for classification. Anything else would be rather dataset-specific. That said, I would set aside a sample as a hold-out and then try different distribution choices.

Comment: And evaluate them against what metric?

Comment: Again the metric you consider more appropriate to your classification problem. (e.g. AUCROC)

Comment: @MichaelM Why not use trees which make no assumptions on the distribution?

Comment: Trees do not make any assumptions on the distribution. In gradient boosting you need to specify the loss function to be optimized, e.g. logloss or mse. Modern implementations like lightgbm or XGBoost just ask for these. The `gbm` package uses another implementation strategy: it asks for the distribution and uses the loss function derived from the corresponding likelihood (plus some special ones). Logloss resp. Cross-entropy is chosen for Bernoulli, mse for normal etc.